# price and total price

Tags: ubercart, forms

```
function module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)  {
  if (substr($form_id, 0, 28) == 'uc_product_add_to_cart_form_') {
    $form['qty']["#title"] =t('Adults');
  }

  if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_210') {
    try {
      if (isset($_GET['pid']) && isset($_GET['attributes'])) {
        $nid = $_GET['pid'];
        $attributes = $_GET['attributes'];

        $node = node_load($nid);
        $type = node_type_get_name($node);
        $form['submitted']['produit']['#default_value'] = $type.' '.$node->title;

        $details_product='';
        foreach ($attributes as $aid => $oid) {

            $attribute = uc_attribute_load($aid,$nid,'product');
            $option = uc_attribute_option_load($oid);
            $product_option = $attribute->label.' : '.$option->name.' | '.$option->price;
            $details_product = $details_product.PHP_EOL .$product_option;

        }
        $form['submitted']['details']['#default_value'] = $details_product;
      }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {}
  }
}
```

Above is my `hook_form_alter` implementation. All I wanted to do is, to generate all options of the product chosen by user, but I want to have the price displayed and calculated like the amount and subtotal like in [Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart) module.